# Docker, importing mysql through dockerfile results in mysql command not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a couple of custom docker images i.e

```
cloudbluedigital/mysql:v-0.1
cloudbluedigital/redis:v-0.1
```

I am now using those images to build laravel image, so in my docker file I have:

```
FROM cloudbluedigital/ubuntu:v-0.2
FROM cloudbluedigital/php:v-0.2
FROM cloudbluedigital/node:v-0.1
FROM cloudbluedigital/mysql:v-0.1
FROM cloudbluedigital/redis:v-0.1

MAINTAINER cloudbluedigital version: 0.1
```

All good and builded, however when I run my new laravel image, I can start redis-server from redis image however mysql command is not found, I have checked mysql image and it is installed there but on my new laravel image it is not installed. Anyone knows why this is happening? Is that a correct setup and is worth ignoring some folders with additional configuration? (I am only using Dockerfile, complete newbie)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Multistage build Dockerfile. So your Dockerfile

```
FROM cloudbluedigital/ubuntu:v-0.2
FROM cloudbluedigital/php:v-0.2
FROM cloudbluedigital/node:v-0.1
FROM cloudbluedigital/mysql:v-0.1
FROM cloudbluedigital/redis:v-0.1

MAINTAINER cloudbluedigital version: 0.1
```

Is actually equivalent to

```
FROM cloudbluedigital/redis:v-0.1

MAINTAINER cloudbluedigital version: 0.1
```

Specifying multiple FROM is only for building artifacts and copying in the final `FROM`. Read below for more details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

You need to use `docker-compose` to run multiple services. Read more details about the same on below

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: okay, I will read those url shortly, meanwhile can you provide me with at least an example of how to configure this? This thing that got me worried is that redis image is pulling ubuntu image but when I was using docker push command it pushed redis image but loaded from cache php image?

Comment: You want everything in same image or run different services? Because install everything in same image means you need to install each software

Comment: I want to have software installed on other services i.e all the images available in my cloudbluedigital/laravel image, think of it as having services spread out and having laravel image as a main general one that has everything, this allows me to split some logic, If I only need mysql and redis for particular project I can just use those 2 images

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel, please look at https://github.com/laradock/laradock

Comment: not only it contains a lot of stuff that we don't need and doesn't have the stuff that is needed. We need our custom docker